# text paste in R

Tags: r, expression, paste

I am using the following command:

```
text(4.2,0.55, expression(paste(P[convs10*"%"*fat], "=0.221")), cex = 1.3)
```

How can I add a space between con vs 10% fat? At the moment all four words are without space.

Thanks

Comment: Yes sorry, it is for a survplot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `~` to create the space

```
plot(1:100)
text(5.5, 1.2, expression(paste(P[con~vs~10*"%"~fat], "=0.221")), cex = 1.3)
```

[image]